# Problem in Youngs double slit experiment

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, geometry, double-slit-experiment, approximations

[image: double slit ray diagram]

This is from Young Double slit experiment. But How to prove the the two $\theta$ are equal, I meant, how  $\angle EAD= \angle PEC$? I see from the both triangle have $90^0$ but what about others?

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): There is an implicit assumption that $d \ll L$.

Comment: @Qmechanic without  guessing any approximation, we can reduce the  path difference $s$ so the angle $\angle BAD ( \theta)$ will be smaller and therefore $\angle PEC ( \theta)$ also be smaller with same rate.  but how can we prove that two angle are same without guessing any approximation.

Comment: They cannot be the same. ∠ABD=90-θ. ∠BEP=90+θ. This makes ∠EPB=0. Essentially EP and BP are parallel lines. This is only a good approximation if d≪L, allowing ∠EPB to be very very close to 0, therefore allowing ∠BAD and ∠PEC to be approximately equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, in Young's double slit experiment, $d << L$.

This means, that that $\mathbf{EP} \approx \mathbf{r_1} \approx \mathbf{r_2}$.

If you draw the picture in scale, you will see, that it is really the case.

$\implies$the angle $P$ - $B$ - ''Point at the right side wall at same height as $B$'' is equal to $\theta$ also, because it is just the same angle as $PEC$. (and because $PE$ || $r_1$ )

$\implies DBA = 90^\circ - \theta \implies BAD = 90^\circ - (90^\circ - \theta) = \theta \text{ }_\Box$

Answer (score -1):

Could you please tell me where did you find this question.

The curvature of Mars is such that its surface drops a vertical distance of 2.0 meters for every 3600 meters tangent to the surface. In addition, the gravitational acceleration near its surface is 0.4 times that near the surface of the Earth. What is the speed a golf ball would need to orbit Mars near the surface, ignoring the effects of air resistance?

Please please it's super urgent

Comment: Welcome @SWATI SINGH. This doesn't seem to be an answer or even relevant to this question. If you have a new different question you should ask it separately, but first check out [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)